# Blender boolean modifier difference make distorsion

Tags: modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, artifacts

I'm trying to create a difference between two objects.
Let's see my object below :
[image]

As you can see, I get a really bad result. I would like to show you my shape before applying the boolean modifier.
[image]

[image]

Any idea how to avoid this distortion ?

Comment: I think it gives what it is supposed to give, to have sharp edges you need to add edge loops close to the one already existing, your boolean won't do it, but could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks, in this case @miceterminator solution is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you apply the Subdivision-surface Modifier AFTER the boolean modifier. This means the hole you try to model using the boolean gets subdivided and "distorted".

The order of modifiers matters!

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed it was because my boolean modifier was before the subdivision modifier.